# Correct way to provide minimal browser-api to Go wasm and returning lib-api back to client, without Global scope?

Tags: go, webassembly

I'm trying to find a **best/right** way to implement minimal and safe **client <-> wasm** api while avoiding usage of `window|global|self` context. I have found 3 working solutions so far which I wrote here as simplified self explaining example. I'm not sure what's the right solution and most likely there are besides these approaches `4th,  5th, nth` solutions. Has anybody found needle in a haystack solution?

```golang
// main.go
package main

import (
    "syscall/js"
    "unsafe"
)

// this would be needed to be here to satisfy this error?
// go:linkname only allowed in Go files that import "unsafe"
var _ unsafe.Pointer

//go:linkname jsGo syscall/js.jsGo
var jsGo js.Value

type ref uint32
type tmpValue struct {
    _     [0]func()
    ref   ref
    gcPtr *ref
}

func hello(this js.Value, args []js.Value) any {
    println("hello " + this.Get("name").String())
    return nil
}

func main() {
    c := make(chan struct{}, 0)

    jsapi1 := js.Global() // not a window anymore
    client1 := jsapi1.Get("client")
    println("replace Global:", client1.Get("name").String())

    jsapi2 := jsGo.Get("jsapi")
    client2 := jsapi2.Get("client")
    println("jsGo.client:", client2.Get("name").String())

    tmp := (*tmpValue)(unsafe.Pointer(&jsapi1))
    tmp.ref = 7
    jsapi3 := (*js.Value)(unsafe.Pointer(tmp))
    client3 := jsapi3.Get("client")
    println("hack the table:", client3.Get("name").String())

    client3.Set("hello", js.FuncOf(hello))
    jsapi3.Get("Object").Call("freeze", client3)
    <-c
}
```

```js
// go.js
export class Go { 
  async run (instance, clientClass = name => ({ name })) {
    /* ... */
    const createJsAPI = (client) => ({
      client, // client api not in global wid
      Object, // browser api's want to provide for wasm.
    })
    // 1 e.g. replace js.Global  
    const replaceGlobalThis = createJsAPI(clientClass('client 1'))
    // 2 e.g. add minimal api to syscall/js.jsGo
    this.jsapi = createJsAPI(clientClass('client 2'))
    // 3 e.g. add new entry ref
    const jsapi = createJsAPI(clientClass('client 3'))

    this._values = [ NaN, 0, null, true, false, replaceGlobalThis, this, jsapi ]
    this._ids = new Map([[0, 1], [null, 2], [true, 3], [false, 4], [replaceGlobalThis, 5], [this, 6], [jsapi, 7]])
    /* ... */
  }
}
// client could also be wrapped with Proxy  
// new Proxy({}, { get: (_, key) => {} } )
export const Client = name => ({ name })
```

**client**

```js
// index.js
import { Go, Client } from 'go.js'

const go = new Go()
const client = Client('client 3')
const wasm = await WebAssembly.instantiateStreaming(fetch(wasmUrl), go.importObject)
go.run(wasm.instance, client)

client.hello()
client.x = 1
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
replace Global: client 1
jsGo.client: client 2
hack the table: client 3
hello client 3
Error: TypeError: Cannot add property x, object is not extensible // as expected
```